# Providing a StringField with a list of choices (strings)

Tags: python, flask, field, default, wtforms

I need a `StringField` with 'multiple defaults' (provided by a list of strings) which are available and shown like a `SelectField` but with the opportunity to write your own text in the field if necessary.

Is there any way to accomplish that?

Comment: HTML doesn't have widget to display list and input text as one object. You will have to build your own object using CSS tricks.

Comment: @furas Thanks for your advise. I really hoped there would be something out of the box.

Comment: Why not just use a select field with a "Other" option and a StringField which shows up when the "Other" option is selected?

Comment: Is this what you are trying to describe? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combo_box

Comment: @jwpfox Yes, absolutely. Now I'm looking something similar for WTForms.

Comment: @sytech Can it be done completely with WTForms? I've got dozens of forms. Sometimes with this kind of request and sometimes not. I just want to have an automation.

Comment: @ericMTR you can customize the HTML rendering done by WTForms, yes. There's a lot of flexibility;  I recommend looking into custom widgets. Lots of different approaches you can use to do this. It could be as simple as adding an 'onchange' attribute to the select field that executes some JS that takes care of this. Another option would be to make a Jinja2 template or a macro that takes in the form as an argument and produces the HTML to your liking. Among many other options... Without knowing more about your case, it's hard to give a specific answer to your question as it's written.